# Parse wikipedia {{Location map}} templates

Tags: parsing, wikipedia, text-parsing

I would like to parse the Wikipedia power plant lists, which contain the {{Location map}} template. In my example I'm using the German translation, but this shouldn't change the basic process.

How can I get out the label=, lat=, lon= and region= parameters from such code?
Probably this is nothing for a html parser like BeautifulSoup, but rather awk?

```
{{ Positionskarte+
 | Tadschikistan
 | maptype     = relief
 | width       = 600
 | float       = right
 | caption     =
 | places      =
 {{ Positionskarte~
  | Tadschikistan
  | label      = <small>[[Talsperre Baipasa|Baipasa]]</small>
  | marktarget =
  | mark       = Blue pog.svg
  | position   = right
  | lat        = 38.267584
  | long       = 69.123906
  | region     = TJ
  | background = #FEFEE9
 }}
 {{ Positionskarte~
  | Tadschikistan
  | label      = <small>[[Kraftwerk Duschanbe|Duschanbe]]</small>
  | marktarget =
  | mark       = Red pog.svg
  | position   = left
  | lat        = 38.5565
  | long       = 68.776
  | region     = TJ
  | background = #FEFEE9
 }}
...
}}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extract information with regular expressions. 
For example like this (`PHP`)

```
$k = "{{ Positionskarte+
 | Tadschikistan
 | maptype     = relief
 | width       = 600
 | float       = right
 | caption     =
 | places      =
 {{ Positionskarte~
  | Tadschikistan
  | label      = <small>[[Talsperre Baipasa|Baipasa]]</small>
  | marktarget =
  | mark       = Blue pog.svg
  | position   = right
  | lat        = 38.267584
  | long       = 69.123906
  | region     = TJ
  | background = #FEFEE9
 }}
 {{ Positionskarte~
  | Tadschikistan
  | label      = <small>[[Kraftwerk Duschanbe|Duschanbe]]</small>
  | marktarget =
  | mark       = Red pog.svg
  | position   = left
  | lat        = 38.5565
  | long       = 68.776
  | region     = TJ
  | background = #FEFEE9
 }}
}}";

$items = explode("Positionskarte~", $k);

$result = [];

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $info = [];
    $pattern1 = '/label\s+=\s+(.+)/';
    preg_match($pattern1, $item, $matches);
    if (!empty($matches)) {
        $info['label'] = $matches[1];       
    }
    $pattern2 = '/lat\s+=\s+(.+)/';
    preg_match($pattern2, $item, $matches);
    if (!empty($matches)) {
        $info['lat'] = $matches[1];     
    }
    $pattern3 = '/long\s+=\s+(.+)/';
    preg_match($pattern3, $item, $matches);
    if (!empty($matches)) {
    $info['long'] = $matches[1];        
    }

    $pattern4 = '/region\s+=\s+(.+)/';
    preg_match($pattern4, $item, $matches);
    if (!empty($matches)) {
        $info['region'] = $matches[1];      
    }

    if(!empty($info)) {
        $result[] = $info;
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to split the label at the pipe symbol? I think I can remove the "<small>" by myself with str_replace.

Comment: Yes, it is possible: `$labelStringParts = explode('|', $labelString);`
 And if you read documentation on `preg_match`, `explode` and `str_replace` functions, you will be able to write to parse just any string with information in `PHP`. Or do the same for your favorite programming language.

Comment: How would it work for {{Location map~|Russia|label=[[Balakovo Nuclear Power Plant|Balakovo]]|lat=52.09121454|long=47.95528861|position=bottom|mark=Location dot red.svg}} ??